# setting up ASUS Transformer as a development device

Tags: android, tablet

Just bought an [ASUS Transformer tablet](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_Pad/Eee_Pad_Transformer_TF101/). Could not connect it as my development device. I did install latest USB driver. Any directions?

Comment: Probably belongs on Superuser.

Comment: What OS are you using on your development machine?
Did you turned on the "development mode" (sorry I don't have a device right now so I don't remember the right voice) in Settings?

Comment: Device has 3.1 and yes I did turn on setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.
Need to install USB driver from Asus. Boot.

Comment: Well, What OS are you running? Windows? Because installing the drivers is pretty straight forward on Windows, but not the case on Mac or Linux. Asus recommends that you use Splashtop Streamer - another App -  for Mac in order to install the drivers. See: http://www.asus.com/support/Download/28/1/Eee_Pad_Transformer_TF101/8/

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the Asus Driver from its website.

You can find a quick tutorial here : http://www.wakeupsun.com/article/develop-asus-transformer/

Answer (score 0):

You should install the latest version, which is *revision 4*. You do that with the *SDK Manager*, aka. *Android SDK and AVD Manager*. The driver is in *Third Party Add-ons*, then in *Google Inc.*

This is true, you may need to do it several times to resolve dependencies

Then adb and ddms are in new locations in the sdk Find them and use the new versions\Bonne Chance
John

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have development options on. Go to "Settings" on your Asus Transformer Pad -> Scroll down to "About" -> Go to "Software information" -> Touch "Build number" like 6x.

Download the driver.